# Ubuntu 14.04 - Sound is tinny with no bass and very low quality.

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa

uname -r: 4.4.0-67-generic

`sudo lspci` shows two devices:

`00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset HD Audio Controller (rev 05)
03:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fba (rev a1)`

I am using the Intel Controller.

`sudo aplay -l` output is

`**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3220 Analog [ALC3220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

The sound is very tinny and hollow. All settings in Alsamixer are turned up and seem correct. What's even stranger is when I use pavucontrol and set the port from Speakers to Headphones in the Output devices the sound seems to work fine, but resets on each reboot or login event.

Comment: I have the same issue on my MSI laptop, even when running in a virtual machine with a Windows host.  But sound coming from Windows sounds fine.  I can't only guess it's because the mixer software or driver doesn't take advantage of the other soundcard settings like treble and bass etc, so the sound is very flat.  I've never been able to find a solution for this problem.

Comment: @Dorian Do you have the same controller (Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset HD Audio Controller (rev 05))?

Comment: I'll have to check this evening, but I believe it's a Realtek.  I'm getting the same issue as you are though.